# Presenting data from a Python file in Pyqt5 GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new to Python (using Python 2.7), and I want to create a GUI using PyQt5.
I saw some tutorials which explain about creation of different GUI components, however my question is regarding connection between a GUI and data - is it must be through a data base, or is it possible that I will have another python file in which I defined a list of object, for example, a Students class  with names and grades. And I want GUI in which I can select a student name and update its grade.
My question - how can I define the students name to appear in the GUI? and then update the new grade in the grade field of the Students class

Comment: Your question is very broad, it is practically asking for guidelines on how to do your project, and that is not the profile of questions we expect in SO. Try to implement your project, and when you have a specific problem then go back to the SO and ask your question indicating what you have tried and what has not worked, read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyQt5 doesn't officially support Python 2.7. There are 3 options you could pursue:

1) Use PyQt4.

2) Use Python 3.

3) Use an unofficial version such as https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5 (only works on windows 64-bit).

As for displaying data in PyQt5, it sounds like you are after [models](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html).

Comment: What you point out is false, I have PyQt5 5.11 installed in python2.7. Also the question is too broad so your answer does not answer it, read [answer] so you can learn to create quality answers.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good direction to start with, and this is what I was looking for